“alignedat" will adjust the line space automatically but "array" won't in LaTeX?
From the post, the array is better than alignedat for aligning the equation. However, it seems that alignedat would adjust the line space but array won't. For example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=&\frac{890}{1234}\\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=&\frac{415}{1423}\\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=&\frac{12}{3456}\\
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle} c @{} >{\displaystyle}c @{} >{\displaystyle}l}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=\frac{890}{1234}\\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=\frac{415}{1423}\\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=\frac{12}{3456}\\
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}



I would like to challenge your claim that "array is better than alignedat for aligning the equation". In your earlier posting, your code doesn't perform any aligning at all, as array and alignedat are both used incorrectly. (Please also see the answer I've posted for your earlier query, in which I propose an alternative solution that does perform the needed alignment.) When used correctly, both array and alignedat can be used to perform alignment operations equally well.

@Mico I still confused. May you tell me where did I wrong in this post with detailed instruction.

Please see the answer I posted.

The array and alignedat tools are thought for different applications: the former strives for keeping equal distances between baselines, the latter doesn't and relies on the normal TeX mechanism for distancing the baselines, adding also \jot vertical space between rows.
This has consequences on how \\[<dimen> is interpreted in the two environments: within array, the <dimen> is added to the depth of the row, within alignedat is added as vertical space between rows.
Very high and deep entries in an array always create problems: if you use \\[<dimen>] you have to guess what the depth is; if you change the value of \arraystretch, you also add to the height of the rows.
Let's do some experiments with your code.
array
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\section{No setting}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle} c @{} >{\displaystyle}c @{} >{\displaystyle}l}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=\frac{890}{1234}
    \\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=\frac{415}{1423}
    \\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}

\section{Changing \texttt{\char`\\arraystretch}}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle} c @{} >{\displaystyle}c @{} >{\displaystyle}l}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=\frac{890}{1234}
    \\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=\frac{415}{1423}
    \\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}

\section{Adding \texttt{\char`\\\char`\\[4ex]}}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{r @{} >{\displaystyle} c @{} >{\displaystyle}c @{} >{\displaystyle}l}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=\frac{890}{1234}
    \\[4ex]
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=\frac{415}{1423}
    \\[4ex]
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{array}
    \right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


alignedat
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\section{No adjustment}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=&\frac{890}{1234}
    \\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=&\frac{415}{1423}
    \\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=&\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 

\section{Changing \texttt{\char`\\jot}}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \setlength{\jot}{6pt}
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=&\frac{890}{1234}
    \\
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=&\frac{415}{1423}
    \\
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=&\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 

\section{Adding \texttt{\char`\\\char`\\[1ex]}}

\begin{equation}
    \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
            f_1&=\frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}&=&\frac{890}{1234}
    \\[1ex]
            f_2&=\frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}=&\frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}&=&\frac{415}{1423}
    \\[1ex]
            f_3&=\frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}=&\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}&=&\frac{12}{3456}
    \end{alignedat}
    \right\}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}


IEEEeqnarraybox
There are also good methods with IEEEeqnarraybox
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\section{No adjustment}

\begin{equation}
\left.
  \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCcCcCl}
  f_1
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}
           {\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}
  &=& \frac{890}{1234}
  \\
  f_2
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}
  &=& \frac{415}{1423}
  \\
  f_3
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}
  &=& \frac{12}{3456}
  \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right\}
\end{equation} 

\section{Changing \texttt{\char`\\jot}}

\begin{equation}
\left.
  \renewcommand*{\IEEEeqnarrayboxdecl}{\setlength{\jot}{3\IEEEnormaljot}}
  \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCcCcCl}
  f_1
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}
           {\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}
  &=& \frac{890}{1234}
  \\
  f_2
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}
  &=& \frac{415}{1423}
  \\
  f_3
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}
  &=& \frac{12}{3456}
  \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right\}
\end{equation} 

\section{Using \texttt{\char`\\\char`\\[1ex]}}

\begin{equation}
\left.
  \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[][c]{rCcCcCl}
  f_1
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{AB}\|}{\|\mathrm{CD}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{\frac{45}{6}}}{789}}
           {\frac{1011 \sqrt{\frac{12}{3}}}{4567}}
  &=& \frac{890}{1234}
  \\[1ex]
  f_2
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{EF}\|}{\|\mathrm{GH}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{123}{456}}{\frac{8907}{123}}
  &=& \frac{415}{1423}
  \\[1ex]
  f_3
  &=& \frac{\|\mathrm{IL}\|}{\|\mathrm{JK}\|}
  &=& \frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{\frac{56}{7}}}{890}}
  &=& \frac{12}{3456}
  \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right\}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}


Final word
I'd recommend the third method, for such objects. Note that the spacing around relation symbols is correct; it should be adjusted with both array and alignedat.


... it seems that alignedat would adjust the line space ...

That's not quite right. The align and related multi-row math environments insert a fixed amount of vertical whitespace, in the amount of \jot (which equals 3pt by default), between rows, in addition to the ordinary interline space (in the present case, \lineskip). [Many thanks, @egreg, for providing the exact language!] In case 3pt isn't enough whitespace, feel free to increase the value of \jot via a suitable \setlength or \addtolength instruction. See the code below for such an example.
I suggest you employ an {alignedat}{3} environment and, where needed, use inline-fraction notation instead of \frac notation to assure that no compound-fraction term has more than 4 "levels". I also suggest running \addtolength{\jot}{3pt} inbetween \begin{equation} and \left., as each line in the three-line expression is quite "tall" to begin with.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert
\newcommand\normrm[1]{\norm{\mathrm{#1}}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\addtolength{\jot}{3pt} % Optional. Default: 3pt (vertical whitespace)
\left.
\begin{alignedat}{3}
f_1&= \frac{\normrm{AB}}{\normrm{CD}}
   &&=\frac{\frac{123 \sqrt{45/6}}{789}}{\frac{1011 \sqrt{12/3}}{4567}}
   &&=\frac{890}{1234}  \\
f_2&= \frac{\normrm{EF}}{\normrm{GH}}
   &&=\frac{123/456}{8907/123}
   &&=\frac{415}{1423}  \\
f_3&= \frac{\normrm{IL}}{\normrm{JK}}
   &&=\frac{\frac{12 \sqrt{345}}{678}}{\frac{1234 \sqrt{56/7}}{890}}
   &&=\frac{12}{3456}
\end{alignedat}
\right\}
\end{equation} 

\end{document}


Not completely correct: align (and variants thereof) insert a \jot of vertical space in addition to the normal interline space (in this case the amount is that of \lineskip).

That's a good approach. However, the alignedat environment can't aligned one of fraction centered.

@Y.zeng - I suppose I misunderstood the point of your question, then. I thought it was about differences in the amounts of vertical space between rows of array and alignedat environments. I didn't realize you were more interested in something quite different. Sorry.

Thanks a lot. You have helped me a lot.
